# I need help to speed up of a Python for-loop with huge amount of calculations

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I am working on a pice of Python software that requires to run a huge amount of calculations. I am talking about up to hundred of millions of calculations or more (n in below code can be 100000 or more). I have realized that Python is not the optimal software for this work but I have no experience with C or C++. Is there a way to speed up the below code in Python or do I need to introduce C or C++? If I need to introduce C or C++, any suggestion for how to embed this in a Python script?

```
import math
import random

a = []
b = []
c = []
x1 = []
x2 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []
tresh = 30 # int or float

n=1000 # n can be up to 100000 or even more
for i in range(n):
    x1.append(random.randint(0, 100))
    x2.append(random.randint(0, 100))
    y1.append(random.randint(0, 100))
    y2.append(random.randint(0, 100))

def calc():
    x1_len = len(x1)
    y1_len = len(y1)

    for n in range(x1_len):
        for m in range(y1_len):
            d = math.sqrt((abs(y1[m] - x1[n])) ** 2 + (abs(y2[m] - x2[n])) ** 2)

            if d >= tresh and d <= tresh:
                a.append((y1[m] + x1[n]) / 2)
                b.append((y2[m] + x2[n]) / 2)
                c.append(d)

    return a,b,c

calc()
```

With my current Python knowledge and experience I don't know how to optimize the code further. I have reviewed a lot of for-loop related questions but not found anything has helped me.

Comment: Is that meaningless example code or does it solve a task that can be described? If the latter, please do.

Comment: Time to construct the x1,x2,y1,y2 lists is relatively insignificant. The problem here is that you will have to calculate the square root-based formula n**2 times. So, for example, with n=1000 this runs in <0.2s on my machine (i.e., one million significant calculations). With n=10000 it takes ~18.5s (i.e., 100 million significant calculations). So you can see where this is going with even larger values for n. Perhaps describe the maths behind this and the objective. There may be a better way - e.g., with numpy

Comment: @Pingu Looks like a geometry task, just with misleading coordinate names. I suspect NumPy is *not* the way to go :-)

Comment: Just noticed this: *if d >= tresh and d <= tresh* You might want to rethink that ;-) It's the same as *if d == tresh* in which case what's the point of the *c* list? It will only ever contain multiple occurrences of *tresh*

Comment: using `10_000` iterations it takes `0.37` seconds in numba so it's most likely best done using numba for the least number of modifications.

Comment: @AhmedAEK 10_000 iterations? So n == 100?

Comment: @Pingu that's for `n = 10_000` , it takes around 43 seconds for `n = 100_000`, but it's far from optimal, knowing that numba cannot multithread this (not without some extra help from python), so there's still a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: @AhmedAEK So 100 million iterations. Understood. Could you share the code?

Comment: x1 and x2 will be x and y coordinates for one point and y1 and y2 coordinates for another point. I could have up to 100000 of each of the points.

Comment: @Pingu i added that in an answer, still i think numba wastes a lot of time on converting numba objects to python objects, which opens even more room for performance improvements.

Comment: *"x1 and x2 will be x and y coordinates"* - So why use such misleading names?

Comment: Are the numbers realistic? You have 100000 points with integer coordinates from 0 to 100 and your tresh is 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a rather simple solution is to use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to compile it to machine code.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


n = 10_000  # n can be up to 100000 or even more
x1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (n,), dtype=np.int64)
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (n,), dtype=np.int64)
y1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (n,), dtype=np.int64)
y2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (n,), dtype=np.int64)
tresh = 30  # int or float


@njit
def calc(x1, x2, y1, y2, tresh):
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    x1_len = len(x1)
    y1_len = len(y1)

    for n in range(x1_len):
        for m in range(y1_len):
            d = math.sqrt((abs(y1[m] - x1[n])) ** 2 + (abs(y2[m] - x2[n])) ** 2)

            if d <= tresh:
                a.append((y1[m] + x1[n]) / 2)
                b.append((y2[m] + x2[n]) / 2)
                c.append(d)

    return a,b,c

calc(x1,x2,y1,y2, tresh)  # warmup for njit

import time
t1 = time.time()
calc(x1, x2, y1, y2, tresh)
t2 = time.time()
print(f"took {t2-t1} seconds")
```

this takes only `3` seconds for `10_000` entires, if you'd like more performance than that then, while multithreading is possible for extra speedup, it's not simple, as you need python to be the one creating the threads, the current numba multithreading API won't manage this properly (because you cannot tell numba to use a serpate list for each thread)

Comment: It's a shame that numba can't be installed with Python 3.11 :-(

Comment: @Pingu sadly `3.11` is currently only used for benchmarks, in the hope that it will one day be usable in production, most code is either ran in `3.10` for language improvements or `3.8` for windows 7 compatibility, (because whether or not anyone likes it, a lot of corporates still use it).

Comment: This was very fast, thanks! A billion calculations took around 20 sec. I will try to implement it in my code and see how it works out. By the way, the (if d >= tresh and d <= tresh: ) should be (if d >= 0 and d <= tresh:). Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @PerHelgeSemb d will **always** be greater than or equal to zero

Comment: How long does it take without the `d >= tresh`?

Comment: @KellyBundy it took `3 seconds` for `n = 10_000` but it ran out of memory on `n = 100_000` on my pc, as python consumes a lot of memory for its "number objects".

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, with points in a 100×100 square, many pairs will have distance ≤30. That's why I suspect it's not realistic (I've asked but they haven't responded yet).

Comment: @KellyBundy, with n= 30000 it took about 20sec without the d >= tresh. I ran out of memory on my laptop for n = 100000 so haven't been able to try it out yet.

Comment: @PerHelgeSemb If the desired *result* is too big for you, what are you going to do? Buy/configure more memory, or change your mind about what result you desire?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use external Python modules like [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html)? It is a fundamental package for scientific numerical computing in Python. It will speed everything up for sure for you.

Other thing - you could generate your random numbers once, then use `extend` instead of `append`. It will also shave some computation time.